# Get certificate's revocation time for signature validation in Java

Tags: java, certificate, signature

I need to get the revocation date just to compare it with the signing time in signature validation framework. The next code, using CertPathValidator java class, allow me to validate a certificate chain but it throw an exception if there is any cert revoked in the chain.

```
private boolean validateChain(List<X509Certificate> certificates) {
 PKIXParameters params;
 CertPath certPath;
 CertPathValidator certPathValidator;
 Boolean valid = Boolean.FALSE;

 params = new PKIXParameters(keyStore);
 params.setRevocationEnabled(true);
 Security.setProperty("ocsp.enable", "true");

 certPath = cf.generateCertPath(certificates);
 certPathValidator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");

 PKIXCertPathValidatorResult result = (PKIXCertPathValidatorResult)  
 certPathValidator.validate(certPath, params);

 if(null != result) {
    valid = Boolean.TRUE;
 }
 return valid;
}
```

I need some way to check if there is some certificate revoked in the chain without throwing an exception and stopping the validation process. Besides, I need getting the date of revocation since the last codes does not allow it.
I need a non propietary solution, since I already know the Sun class OCSP http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/provider/certpath/OCSP.java.html

Comment: You could try using the Bouncy Castle libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843654/how-to-get-x-509-certificate-status-by-bouncy-castle

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a workaround. It can be established the date for which the validity of the path should be determined as a parameter. I cannot recover the revocation date of each certificate but adding the line:

```
params.setDate(signingDate)
```

The validity of the CertPath is checked at this time